# Python script and Google Cloud Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How to upload a Python script in Google Cloud(via Compute Engine>VM instance). The python file generates a csv file output data via REST). For this, I want to create a Scheduler to run this python file and generate that csv file. Once the csv file is generated, I need help to upload it into Firestore.

Any recommendation or advice where to go. I have:

1. go to GCP
2. go to Compute Engine.
3. Create an Instance.
4. Go to SSH run command line, and create a python folder.
5. AND run scheduler.
   6....

Comment: Your question might be too broad as you are presenting multiple challenges in one question. Break your task into multiple parts. Example, upload a file is very different from creating a scheduled program. Then create separate questions. Show the work and research that you have done and clearly state your problem. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which part you can't figure out ? It looks like you got covered generating a csv file but don't know how to upload it autoamtically to Firestore - is that it ?

Comment: Thank you, Chris. It is working that part. I have managed to upload the python script-files and run it. I'm missing where should I go to see if it is working. And, where should I go to see where the csv file will be uploaded. Maybe same directory.